# Ready iCloud + Core Data solution

Tags: debugging, core-data, icloud

I spent 10 days trying to debug iCloud connection for my (extra cool) app coming... Its really hard to set up when you use Core Data. Now it doesn't work on device with iCloud on.
I want to ask if there is ready open-source solution to copy&paste code to my app for it finally to run?

Thanks!
***Not interested in iCloud analogs like parse, dropbox...

Answer (score 0):

There's code around, but code is not the problem. In the current versions of Mac OS X and iOS, and in the current version of whatever server side code they're using, Core Data with iCloud often just fails to work. This happens even if your code is exactly right. Start with Apple's sample code (including the **SharedCoreData** example from WWDC 2012), and if you have specific questions, ask them. But getting the code just right is not enough. File bugs and hope that future versions of Mac OS X and iOS are better.